# How to chain animations api10?

Tags: android, api, animation

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.g_out);



        g = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gout);
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService2.class));



        SceneAnimation come = new SceneAnimation(g, out,duration);
        SceneAnimation circled = new SceneAnimation(g, circled,durationc);

       come.play(1);



       circled.play(1);









    }







}



class SceneAnimation {
public int x;
public ImageView mImageView;
public int[] mFrameRess;
public int[] mDurations;
public int mDuration;

public int mLastFrameNo;
public long mBreakDelay;



 public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int[] pDurations)
 {

    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDurations = pDurations;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

    play(1);
   }

    public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration){
    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDuration = pDuration;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

    mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[0]);

    playConstant(1);
   }

    public SceneAnimation(ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration, long pBreakDelay){            
    mImageView = pImageView;
    mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
    mDuration = pDuration;
    mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;
    mBreakDelay = pBreakDelay;

    mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[0]);
    playConstant(1);
}


   public void play(final int pFrameNo)
{


    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {


            mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[pFrameNo]);
            if(pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo)
                {
                return;}
            else
                play(pFrameNo + 1);
        }
    }, mDurations[pFrameNo]);
}


public void playConstant(final int pFrameNo){
    mImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {                    
            mImageView.setImageResource(mFrameRess[pFrameNo]);

            if(pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo)
                playConstant(0);
            else
                playConstant(pFrameNo + 1);
        }
    }, pFrameNo==mLastFrameNo && mBreakDelay>0 ? mBreakDelay : mDuration);
}



};
```

Im looking for the solution to get the 2 SceneAnimation()'s in onCreate() to play one after each other, they play at the same time and one is longer than the other one so the second plays first and then the first kicks in where the frames where the second ends on itself, i heard of AnimationListener but i dont know how to incorperate it into the class to be listened to, i would be grateful for a walkthrough or code examples and explanations i am very new to this, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite simple. Create an Animation instance and attach an AnimationListener to it. In the onAnimationEnd you start your second animation. Et voila, two animations that are executed sequentially.

```
    Animation firstAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(getApplicationContext(), null);
    firstAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Animation secondAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(getApplicationContext(), null);
            secondAnimation.start();
        }
    });

    firstAnimation.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.widget.ImageView;

class SceneAnimation {
public int x;
public ImageView mImageView;
public int[] mFrameRess;
public int[] mDurations;
public int mDuration;

public int mLastFrameNo;
public long mBreakDelay;

private AnimationListener mAnimationListener;

public SceneAnimation( ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int[] pDurations ) {

mImageView = pImageView;
mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
mDurations = pDurations;
mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

play( 1 );
}

public SceneAnimation( ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration ) {
mImageView = pImageView;
mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
mDuration = pDuration;
mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;

mImageView.setImageResource( mFrameRess[0] );

playConstant( 1 );
}

public SceneAnimation( ImageView pImageView, int[] pFrameRess, int pDuration, long     pBreakDelay ) {
mImageView = pImageView;
mFrameRess = pFrameRess;
mDuration = pDuration;
mLastFrameNo = pFrameRess.length - 1;
mBreakDelay = pBreakDelay;

mImageView.setImageResource( mFrameRess[0] );
playConstant( 1 );
}

public void setAnimationListener(AnimationListener listener){
this.mAnimationListener = listener;
}

public void play( final int pFrameNo ) {

mImageView.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mImageView.setImageResource( mFrameRess[pFrameNo] );
        if ( pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo ) {
            return;
        } else
            play( pFrameNo + 1 );

        // Callback when animation ends.
        if( mAnimationListener != null ){
            mAnimationListener.onAnimationEnd();
        }
    }
}, mDurations[pFrameNo] );
}

public void playConstant( final int pFrameNo ) {
mImageView.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mImageView.setImageResource( mFrameRess[pFrameNo] );

        if ( pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo )
            playConstant( 0 );
        else
            playConstant( pFrameNo + 1 );

        // Callback when animation ends.
        if( mAnimationListener != null ){
            mAnimationListener.onAnimationEnd();
        }
    }
}, pFrameNo == mLastFrameNo && mBreakDelay > 0 ? mBreakDelay : mDuration );
}


public static interface AnimationListener {
public void onAnimationEnd();
// You can add onAnimationStart(), and do the same thing like onAnimationEnd.
}
};
```